# Debugger that can show text and data segments

Tags: debugging, memory

I am interested in taking a look at the entire virtual memory of my loaded program; I know Visual Studio can show me the stack and heap, but is there a tool (on Windows or Linux) that I can use to see the full memory layout and sizes of the text, data, as well as the stack and heap segments at a given breakpoint?

**EDIT:**
I was not immediately able to find a tool that lets me see what is contained in the data and text segments. This tool would allow me to see which data and variables appear on the stack and what data is saved on the data segment.

Comment: Did you google search? What did you find?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Thank you for suggestion. However, I was unable to find a tool that seemed useful. For Visual Studio for instance, it seems only to be able to reveal the stack and heap, not the other segments.

Comment: You should mention in the question that you tried to google search but couldn't find anything. That will enhance your question and will increase the likelihood of getting an answer.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I've revised my question. Thanks.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

**size** command in linux list section sizes and total size.
Refer the man page of [size](https://linux.die.net/man/1/size) to know its usage.

Comment: Thanks Hardik Sanghvi - if I wanted to examine what is actually in the text and data segments, would I just need to use a hex reader to open the executable file?